# Huge upvotes on primitive questions with no research background

Tags: discussion

I have came across tons of questions having huge upvotes which ask about primitive features one can get from simple google search like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/how-do-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-in-a-textview-in-android?rq=1/) one for example which tempts users like me to ask such questions and therefore get banned or restricted from asking. Why do they have such huge upvotes?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​asked Jan 11 **'09** - things were simpler back then.

Comment: *Irony-asks a question about question not showing research effort...something that is asked often on meta*

Comment: @codeMagic metaStack is a haven for irony :D

Comment: Now, this brings me to my next question, what to do after receiving such treatment for my question?
Delete it or let it be?

Comment: @AbhaySharma You can't delete it- You can only delete a question that has no answers, or has only one answer that is not upvoted. Duplicate questions don't hurt anything, anyway.

Comment: It had 6 years of high Google hit ranking, collecting over half a million views.  About 0.15% of the visitors thought it worthy for a helpful vote.  Still impressed?  If envy is the problem then consider that you might just not have enough patience.

Comment: *which tempts users like me to ask such questions* only if you did not read [Ask]

Comment: [Life isn't fair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202652/165773)

Comment: @Hans Passant- Not visitors, stack overflow members with at least 15 rep  and who therefore knew which questions should be upvoted, All visitors don't have right to vote.

Comment: @plutonix- I know those rules but clear violation of those and still heavy upvotes will still tempt people aware of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can look at it from two sides.

- **They're older questions, and have been here longer.**  Their age and the view count of the question alone indicates that it's been seen by a lot of people in its time, and a lot of them felt that it was helpful to their cause.
- **They asked the question *first*.**  This person was able to ask the basic questions on the site when it was first up and coming, so it stands to reason that a question that would be asked similar to it *today* would be downvoted and closed, if nothing else, because it's already been asked before.

Comment: Questions about solving common issues in bleeding edge technology get a lot of attention. Sometimes Stack Overflow is the only source for these types of solutions. I completely agree with the second bullet point here.

Comment: Note this a countinuous phenomemon and is not limited to questions that were posted when the site was young. Swift's [Get the length of a String](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24037711/464709) tallies nearly 200 votes and was posted last year.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi:  I'd say that's more due to the novelty of the language.  It's a fair point to add, though.

Comment: Oh, yes, definitely. But new technologies will keep emerging in the future, so that behavior will repeat continuously in the long run.